# Inverse functions (maximal)

Tags: functions

Consider the function $f:[2, \infty) \rightarrow R, f(x)=x^{4}+2(a-4) x^{2}-8 a x+1,$ where $a \in R$
The maximal set of values of $a$ for which the inverse function $f^{-1}$ exists is

A. $(-9, \infty)$

B. $(-\infty, 1)$

C. $[-9,1]$

D. $[-8, \infty)$

E. $(-\infty,-8]$

My answer:

$f^{\prime}(x)=0$

then

$x=2, x=-1 \pm \sqrt{1-a}$

$-1+\sqrt{1-a} \leq 2$

$\sqrt{1-a} \leq 3$

$1-a \leq 8$

$-8 \leq a$

and

$1-a \geq 0$

$1 \geqslant a$

$ \therefore -8 \leq a \leq 1$

but the answer is

$[-8, \infty)$

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in requiring $1-a \ge 0$. It comes from your solution to $f'(x)=0$, which is equivalent to

$$f'(x)=4x^4+4(a-4)ax-8a = 4(x-2)(x^2+2x+a) = 0.$$

Now $x=2$ is obviously a solution to that (second factor), and if you solve the quadratic equation that makes the third factor zero, you get your solutions $x=+1\pm\sqrt{1-a}$. But if that quadratic equation does not have a real solution at all (equivalent to $a>1$), that is not a problem.

Since the third factor is a quadratic term with postive coefficient before $x^2$, it not having a root means its values are positive for all real $x$, so that means your derivate $f'(x)$ is for $x>2$ a product of 3 positive terms, so positive. That means the function is strictly increasing in the interval $[2,\infty)$, so inversible.